# In what situations or problems would I use KDL data type in tf?

Tags: ros, kinematics, library

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is KDL used by tf to do transforms or is it a supplement to explicitly do transforms by the programmer instead of letting tf do it?  Please forgive my ignorance I've been trying to get a better understanding of tf but am confused by KDL.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/128406/in-what-situations-or-problems-would-i-use-kdl-data-type-in-tf?/) by [billtecteacher](https://answers.ros.org/users/9406/billtecteacher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2014-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

TF and KDL can achieve somewhat similar, but somewhat different uses. TF does not use KDL internally.

TF is frequently used when you just want to transform data from one coordinate frame to another.

KDL can also be used to find where a particular frame is based on a kinematic chain and joint positions, but doesn't offer the convenient functions for transforming sensor data. KDL does however offer kinematics functions such as Inverse Kinematics, Forward Kinematics, Jacobian calculations, etc.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billtecteacher](https://answers.ros.org/users/9406/billtecteacher/) on 2014-02-11**:
Thank you so much for your help :)